# I'm unsure how to create a stacked bar chart that in R that shows the occurrences of a variable broken up by month

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, r-markdown

My dataset, sharks for example, contains a variable of the species name, classified as a factor, and a variable month, also classified as a factor. What I want to do is create a separate bar chart for each month to show the number of each species caught in that month. Alternatively, a single stacked bar chart to show all 12 months. I've started a ggplot code, however, I don't know what to use as the y variable, as that should be the count for each species.

```
ggplot(sharks, aes(fill = Species.Name, y = count, x = Month)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")
```

A sample of the dataset:

```
Species Name,Date,Area,Location,Latitude,Longitude,Length (m),Water Temp (C),Month,Day of Week
BLACKTIP REEF WHALER,2016-07-27,Townsville,Radical Bay,-19°6.51,146°52.63,1.1,24,July,Wednesday
BLACKTIP REEF WHALER,2016-07-29,Townsville,The Strand,-19°14.44,146°48.77,1.13,23,July,Friday
BLACKTIP REEF WHALER,2016-09-24,Townsville,Florence Bay,-19°7.3,146°53.12,1.25,27,September,Saturday
BLACKTIP REEF WHALER,2016-10-19,Cairns,Holloways Beach,-16°49.82,145°44.85,0.85,26,October,Wednesday
BLACKTIP REEF WHALER,2016-10-21,Mackay,Harbour Beach,-21°7.08,149°13.62,1.8,25,October,Friday
BLACKTIP REEF WHALER,2016-12-17,Gladstone,Tannum Sands,-23°56.91,151°22.9,0.9,27,December,Saturday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-02,Gold Coast,Tallebudgera Beach,-28°5.47,153°28.26,2.5,25,January,Saturday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-06,Capricorn Coast,Lammermoor Beach,-23°9.16,150°46.2,0.98,27,January,Wednesday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-07,Mackay,Bucasia Beach,-21°1.46,149°9.97,2.2,26,January,Thursday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-10,Mackay,Eimeo Beach,-21°1.8,149°10.8,2,26,January,Sunday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-12,Rainbow Beach,Rainbow Beach,-25°53.92,153°5.87,2.85,25,January,Tuesday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-21,Capricorn Coast,Yeppoon,-23°7.58,150°45.28,0.83,27,January,Thursday
BULL WHALER,2016-01-30,Capricorn Coast,Emu Park,-23°15.66,150°49.92,1.14,28,January,Saturday
```

The full dataset has about 24 species of sharks, so I think a stacked bar graph with a legend would be the best option, as I suspect the names won't all fit under a typical bar graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count` to find the count of Species in each month. Try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sharks %>%
  count(Species.Name, Month = factor(Month, month.name)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Species.Name, y = n, x = Month)) + 
  geom_col()
```